# List does not maintain scroll position

Tags: android, listview

Every Activity in my application (as this is managed by Android) retains its scroll position when you leave and return to the screen.

For example: If I scroll half way down a list and then press some button that takes me to another Activity, pressing the back button and returning to my list will present the list still scrolled to the middle.

Every Activity except 1.

I can not figure out why. I do nothing weird and nothing with this list that is different than any of the other lists in my application.  I realize I'm not presenting any code here.  I wouldn't know what to present as, again, I'm not doing anything weird.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can investigate?

Answer (score 0):

What `collection` are you using?  If you are reassigning an `array` to the `arrayadapter` this will reset your position.  Be weary of recreating objects like this as it will create larger memory space consumption and will not perform as expected.

Also if the `arrayadapter` is assigned in the `OnResume()` or `OnStart()` methods that may also be problematic.